# What the difference between vcc, +5v, and v+?

Tags: schematics

It is my first experience in making electrical circuits on the breadboard. I'm trying to create an "avr fuse bit doctor" device to restore fuses programmed in my atmega328p microchip (I mistakenly set before). There are plenty of things I can't understand in the scheme
Here it is:

[image]
Ok, I understand that +5V is the current source with 5 volts, but what are the other two, vcc and v+?

Comment: look at IC1 ...

Comment: Ah it seems I can't inline pictures in other people's post. I'll need an adult (higher-reputation user) to do that please.

Answer (score 1):

"Vcc" is the power to the controlling ATmega8 microcontroller. It should be 5V.

"+5V" is the power line to the microcontroller being programmed. It is derived from Vcc and controlled by the ATMega8 so it is not always 5V.

"V+" is a higher voltage used to perform the high voltage programming. It should be at least 12V.

"+12V" is the high voltage signal sent to the microcontroller being programmed. It is derived from "V+" and is controlled by the ATMega8 so it is not always 12V.

That is, you just need to connect 5V to Vcc and a high voltage supply to V+. You don't have to worry about "+5V" and "+12V".